# What is the performance difference between a keys_only query and a projection query over a single KeyProperty?

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine

It is well-known that a keys_only query in app engine is fast.

Google App Engine now has the ability to run "projection queries" which can return only parts of the entity data

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries?hl=pl#projection

Assuming I had a model with a large set of properties and records (deserialization costs are high), I'm wondering what the performance difference is between running a projection query that returns a single KeyProperty on that object vs doing a keys_only query?

Would not both of those approaches use only the indexes, making them equally performant?  Or is there something inherent inside of a keys_only query that would make it faster?

A simplistic example:

```
class SomeObject(ndb.Model):
   user = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

what is the performance difference between:

```
SomeObject.query().fetch(1000, projection=["user"])
```

and

```
SomeObject.query().fetch(1000, keys_only=True)
```

---

### WHY?

this isn't exactly the "why", but its close enought:  I'm weighing the differences between a data model that

**splits the data into separate Kinds and uses Entity Groups to keys_only the child then get_multi the parents** (similar to the messaging app shown in Bret Slatkins Google I/O video)

vs.

**putting the parent key into the child table then using projection query only get the parent keys, then get_multi the parents**

there are many other considerations that I wont bore you with... but if I knew the answer to this performance question, it would whittle down my design options

Yes, I will likely do my own testing locally... but would be awesome to have a definite answer from someone in-the-know... and also good to share this knowledge since I haven't been able to find it anywhere as of yet

Thank you!

---

### UPDATE

some basic testing is showing me that a keys_only query is about 10x faster than a full query (which aligns with research)... and that a projection query on a single KeyProperty  takes about twice as long as a keys_only query (so about 5x faster)

Comment: I'm pretty sure knowing the answer to this requires knowing the inner workings of the GAE database (Big Table, last time I checked, could be Dremel now though), but it seems to me that a key query will always be faster, period. A key is essentially a path to the entity, so it wouldn't need an index lookup -- at least, not in the sense that a regular query does.

Comment: Hmm... keys_only also uses memcache if I am not mistaken. Also all your tests have to be carefull what cache settings the have applied.

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple. Keys_only parameter is faster that projection because there is getted from database only Key for object that you provide. The projection provide the key for that object and cutted his data.
Projection execution is something like this:

1. Get key from database
2. Read object using key
3. Cut down unwanted data

Keys_only execution is only first point from that list. That flow that i wrote is not 100% proper because GAE do second and third step in one but that list should show you why this work like that and why you gain that diff between results.